# Loadrunner IE truClient

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, certificate, loadrunner, truclient

I am having a problem with certificates in IE truClient. I have everything sorted out and working using Firefox truClient, but need to test with IE also.

I have deleted the certificates in the browser. When visiting the site(s) I am challenged on the certificate. I don't install/accept the certificate, just exit.

The same path recording the script does not challenge me. I believe if I were to be challenge and the certificate accepted I'd have the same type of files in IE that I have in FF to accompany the script when it runs on the load generators.

I am running LR 11.52 patch 1. What am I missing so that the script will run on the generators?

Answer (score 0):

From a server perspective, if there is no difference in the request made from IE as Firefox then there is a zero technical basis for having to switch browsers

Comment: Agreed, but those requests are not initiated identically from within the web page, which is also to be considered here. My testing is done for a school district which officially only supports IE and the executive level wants to know how performance is from IE.

Comment: Then run the majority of the load as HTTP transport virtual users and one GUI virtual user with a full browser